# How to show Product Subcategories on categories page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want on my woocomerce wordpress site to click on the product category and to show me the subcategories first and then the products...

something like that.

```
     <?php if (is_category()) { 
$this_category = get_category($cat);
}
?>
<?php
if($this_category->category_parent)
$this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id
&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent.
"&echo=0"); else
$this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=1
&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID.
"&echo=0");
if ($this_category) { ?> 

<ul>
<?php echo $this_category; ?>

</ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215747/woocommerce-display-nested-list-of-all-subcategories-on-archive-product-php

Comment: first i want to display all the product categories with the images in one page  and then to click on the category (image or text) and  display all the subcategories products and then the products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function show_product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {    
    if(!is_shop()) //not shop page
    {
        $parentid = get_queried_object_id();

        $args = array(
            'parent' => $parentid,
            'hide_empty' => false,
        );
        $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
        if ( $terms ) {
            echo '<div class="sub_categories">
                <ul class="product-cats cat_products_list">';
                foreach ( $terms as $category ) {
                    wc_get_template('content-product_cat.php',array('category'=>$category));
                }
            echo '</ul><div class="clearfix"></div></div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'show_product_subcategories', 50 );
```